# Using SNMP to monitor windows RDP logons?

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop, query

It is possible to monitor WIN RDP logons (user,login duration) using SNMP specific OID ?

Comment: You did not mention the distro of Linux you are running but the "who" command is fairly universal. https://linux.die.net/man/1/who

Comment: Could I use "who" though to query who is logged onto a remote windows machine from a remote location?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the MIBs that are available for Windows systems, however through some search I have figured out that an added problem is that the OID values change from version to version.

Taking a shortcut though, I suggest that you check the munin take on how to get the number of RDP users:
https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/master/plugins/node.d/snmp__rdp_users

I know that this is not a complete answer, but I suppose that it is a good pointer to start searching.